# GitLab CI runner with shell executor unable to clone Git repo (Docker executor works)

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've got a local GitLab server running, and a bunch of GitLab CI runners. All of the runners are Docker executors and I've never run into any authentication issues.

Now on one of these (already working) runners I'd like to run a second CI runner with the 'shell' executor. So I registered another runner which went all worked fine. However, upon job execution, the job fails in the preparation phase with this authentication error:

```
...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 10...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/abc/0/dev/repo/.git/
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab-server/dev/repo.git/'
...
```

Which works out-of-the box just fine if I choose the 'docker' executor for a second runner.

What I tried:

- Checking this behavior on other runner servers (the same).
- Looking into using deploy keys/tokens etc. to work around this, but it doesn't make any sense why cloning *would* work in a Docker container, but *wouldn't* work for a shell runner.

Can anyone point me at where look next? Or which log files to check? What's the difference between the Git cloning behavior for a 'docker' executor and a 'shell' executor? I can't find anything on this in the documentation.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

---

My GitLab version is: 13.10.1-ee

The CI runner servers are all local, bare-minimum Ubuntu Server 18 installations without any special configurations. They are just running `gitlab-runner`, that's it.

For completeness, here's the `config.toml` for the runner:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "test-runner"
  url = "http://gitlab-server/"
  token = "..."
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "busybox:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "test-runner"
  url = "http://gitlab-server/"
  token = "..."
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "bash"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
```